# SET_AUTHENTICATION_FROM_WALLET call returns ACL error

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, acl

Running Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production.  Have a wallet setup containing a basic authentication credential.
PL/sql package is executing a request over https to an external server.  The acl seems to be setup correctly, as when I issue a request as below, and do some gets, I get results back.

```
D_Request_context := UTL_HTTP.CREATE_REQUEST_CONTEXT(
                                 wallet_path     => D_Path,
                                 wallet_password => NULL,
                                 enable_cookies  => FALSE
                              );

    D_Req := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST(
                  url             => D_Url,
                  method          => C_METHOD,
                  http_version    => C_VERSION,
                  request_context => D_Request_context      )
```

If I call the same code, but include this call

```
   UTL_HTTP.SET_AUTHENTICATION_FROM_WALLET(
            r         => D_Req,
            alias     => 'myalias',
            scheme    => C_SCHEME,
            for_proxy => false
         );
```

I get this error:

```
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-06512: at line 52
ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 450
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP"
```

So why does the call to BEGIN_REQUEST get through the ACL, but the SET_AUTHENTICATION_FROM_WALLET, gets an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a wallet requires an ACE (new name of ACL) as well.

[SET_AUTHENTICATION_FROM_WALLET Procedure](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/UTL_HTTP.html#GUID-4A74C20F-9544-4123-AF8D-B5588503B6C4)

> **Usage Notes**
>
> To use the password credentials in a wallet, the UTL_HTTP user must
>   have the use-passwords privilege on the wallet.

[Configuring Access Control to an Oracle Wallet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/dbseg/managing-fine-grained-access-in-pl-sql-packages-and-types.html#GUID-0BCB5925-A40F-4507-95F9-5DA4A1919EBD)

Example:

```
BEGIN
 DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.APPEND_WALLET_ACE (
  wallet_path => 'file:/home/oracle/wallet',
  ace         => xs$ace_type(privilege_list => xs$name_list('use_passwords'),
                             principal_name => 'YOUR_USER',
                             principal_type => xs_acl.ptype_db));
END;
/
```